# How to implement templating on UWP/UAP

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, template-engine, windows-10-universal

I need to generate HTML based off some models in an UWP/UAP project - written in C# entirely.

The problem is that no preexisting templating engines (I really wouldn't want to write one from scratch) are compatible with the platform. I looked up a few most popular alternatives, and none would work out of the box.

What would be your suggested solution for this substantive issue I am facing? I thought about porting one of available open-source libraries, but I'm not sure whether it would be worth the effort.

I'm not interested in opinionated answers, or recommendations of templating engines (that don't really work on UAP), only in the easiest route to solve the problem of templating in a Windows 10 universal app.

Comment: This is to broad question. But I use https://mustache.github.io/ with javascript.

Comment: @ErkanDemirel -- not it's not the broadness that's the problem.  Requests for recommendations of external resources like libraries are specifically off-topic.

Comment: @roryap there's plenty of (highly voted) questions about templating engines on this site.

Comment: @KonradMorawski -- Sure, and they would be questions about substantive issues or problems, and not requests for recommendations.  Your first sentence "Do you know of any template engine library" clearly indicates that this is off topic.

Comment: @KonradMorawski -- Here's a direct quote from the "reasons to close":  Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @ErkanDemirel it can't be used on UAP, hence my question

Comment: @roryap I rephrased the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are developing, using `HTML/JavaScript`, you can use built-in `WinJS` library for templating in `HTML`. Also Microsoft created a number of [adapters](https://github.com/winjs) for `Angular`, `React` or `Knockout` to use them in `UWP` apps.

Usually most of `JavaScript` code should just work, the only thing you should take into consideration is [security limitations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh849625.aspx) while embedding iframes or external script. To bypass such limitations you should update logic of used library or manually enforce by using the `execUnsafeLocalFunction` method.

```
MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function() {
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.innerHTML = '<div style="color:' + textColor + '">example</div>';
});
```

==
Update:

For C# there are two options:

1. continue looking for library or impellent it yourself that will do such convertion, or
2. build a wrapper around webview control, that will do it for you with already existing libraries.

In the second case it should be quite easy: 
1) You should implement a converter from JSON to HTML (with template) using any library of your choose in JavaScript, it should be available for calling from external context (global function or object). Such function should receive data as a JSON-string and return a string (e.g. from innerHTML).
2) Use standard technics with InvokeScriptAsync/ScriptNotify event for the WebView control to transfer data between C# and JS environments. You don't need actually to display WebView inside your page. Just use it as environment for JS execution with access to DOM, required by corresponding libraries.

Here is code sample with WinJS:
**HTML/JS.** template.html file with WinJS library. Global js-function:

```
function convertFromJSON2HTML(jsonString, templateHTML) {
    var templateEl = document.createElement("div");
    templateEl.innerHTML = templateHTML;

    var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonString);

    if (WinJS != undefined) {
        var template = new WinJS.Binding.Template(templateEl);

        //promise
        template.render(jsonData).done(function(output) {
            window.external.notify(output.innerHTML);
        });
    } else {
           // catch error
    }
}
```

**C# Code**

```
public async Task<string> GenerateTemplate(string jsonData, string template)
{
    var webView = new WebView();
    webView.Source = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///HTML/template.html");

    webView.DOMContentLoaded += async (o, e) =>
    {
        await webView.InvokeScriptAsync("convertFromJSON2HTML", new string[] { jsonData, template });
    };            

    string output = "";

    // Simple trick to convert event result to async result
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    webView.ScriptNotify += (o, e) =>
    {
        output = e.Value;
        tcs.SetResult(true);
    };
    await tcs.Task;
    return output;
}
```

**Usage.** I'm using WinJS-style templates here:

```
var result = await GenerateTemplate("{\"x\":\"test\"}","<p data-win-bind='textContent:x'></p>");
resultBox.Text = result;
```

Also to simplify communications I would recommend to use the AddAllowedWebObject method to pass WinRT-objects between two environments instead of just text.

Comment: I use C#, that's why I tagged the question as C#

Comment: I suggest to put that into the question it self, as it still not clear.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: OK, I updated the question to remove ambiguity. Thanks for your insights. Any specific JavaScript library you would suggest? I guest it's possible, although a bit Rude Goldberg-esque, C# to Json, Json to JavaScript, then HTML out of a "fake" WebView... still it might be what I'll do, if there are no better alternatives. +1 for for offering more options.

Comment: Any light-weight library should work for you. I added a sample with WinJS.